# TradeOff between creating a new RestTemplate each Time and Creating a Single Class returning same Rest Template

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, resttemplate

In Spring Boot,for making a Rest Client call currently creating RestTemplate using the new keyword in multiple classes.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
```

Planning to create a single class that returns a same instance of RestTemplate, and using it for all the Rest calls.

Will it affect performance. What may be the drawbacks on performance or any other?

Also instead of creating a single RestTemplate, is using Pooling a better option?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you make use of Spring Dependency Injection? Inject the rest template through dispatcher servlet and autowire it, where ever required.

Comment: Using Spring Boot. Plan to autowire the RestTemplate class where ever required. Had the question will using single RestTemplate through out affect performance or any other drawback?

Comment: No it won't and probably will improve performance as you don't have the overhead of constructing the same object(s) over and over.

Comment: Thanks Deinum. Also instead of using a single RestTemplate is creating RestTemplate pool a good idea?

Comment: Use a single instance.  Don't create another object, simply register it using @Bean for example in the configuration file and then inject as normal.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new RestTemplate every time you need to use it will be more expensive then just creating it once and using dependency injection to get a reference to it.

Creating a connection pool would provide an additional performance boost because it would allow connections to be re-used (if that is what you need)